# Atonement in Eastern Orthodoxy

Tags: soteriology, eastern-orthodox, christology, atonement

The mainline protestant idea of Atonement is, as Luther himself put it, this:

> Jesus Christ, our God and Lord, died for our sins and was raised again
>   for our justification (Romans 3:24–25). He alone is the Lamb of God
>   who takes away the sins of the world (John 1:29)

Eastern Orthodox will keep speaking about theosis and about sin as  an "disease".

But what does the atonement, the death on the cross and the resurrection of Jesus Christ mean for Eastern Orthodox?
What does Eastern Orthodoxy understands about Christ being  `the Lamb of God who takes away the sins of the world (John 1:29)`?

Did Christ died for my sins? Was he raised again for my justification?

Comment: No time for a full answer. But Orthodoxy takes seriously that atonement involves at-one-ment, i.e., becoming one with God (in his energies, not in his essence). Salvation is an event accomplished by Christ and a process applied to us as we partake of the divine nature, but ultimately it is a person: Salvation *is* Jesus Christ the Savior. Clearly Christ is the paschal lamb, as beautifully portrayed in the eucharistic worship of the Divine Liturgy every week and throughout eternity. Christ gave up his life for our life. He defeated sin, death, and the cosmic powers of evil.

Comment: Christ saves us by becoming what we are, sharing completely in our humanity, thereby enabling us to share in what he is (we become by grace what he is by nature). The emphasis is thus equally on "Christ *in* us" as much as it is on "Christ *for* us."

Comment: He did indeed die for you, but not simply to absolve you from a forensic/juridicial penalty, but to heal and transform your humanness. Also, of great importance, salvation is communal and social, not individualistic and isolated. We are created in the image of God, who exists as Trinity, an inherently relational being. My salvation is bound up in the salvation of my neighbor. No one is saved alone. We are not saved *from* but *with* the world.